# Show the stalk of $Spec( \mathbb{Z}/60)$ at $(2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/4$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

> Show the stalk of $Spec( \mathbb{Z}/60)$ at $(2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/4$

It seems that this question has appeared at this site, but I want to use the following proposition to solve it.
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00CT

Applying this we can have the stalk is $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}/(60\mathbb{Z})_{(2)}$. But I have no idea how to show that it’s $\mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}$...

Thanks for any help..

Comment: The fact that you're taking it at (2) means that the (3) and the (5) factors go away, since they're coprime to 2.  So the only factors that remain are the 2 2's in the factorization of 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3$ and $5$ are invertible in the localization $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$, so that $\mathbb Z_{(2)} / (60\mathbb Z)_{(2)} = \mathbb Z_{(2)} / (4\mathbb Z)_{(2)}$.

There is a natural isomorphism $\mathbb Z_{(2)} / (4\mathbb Z)_{(2)} \cong (\mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z)_{(2)}$. Because $\mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z$ is a local ring and $(2)$ is its maximal ideal, localization at $(2)$ doesn't do anything: $(\mathbb Z / 4\mathbb Z)_{(2)} \cong \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$.